# onChange handler doesn't fire when using custom-component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, onchange, formik

I'm using [Formik](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik) for validation in a React app.

Validation is working correctly, but my onChange handler does not fire:

```
  <Field
    type="text"
    name="name"
    placeholder="First Name"
    component={Input}
    onChange={() => console.log("gfdg")}
  />
```

[Link to Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lp58rkkmkm)

Why is this?

Comment: https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1243 this discusses your issue, but to be honest, i would consider getting rid of that formik library which seems to be way too complicated just to achieve a validation....but i am not familiar with formik. Maybe this is useful...

Comment: @messerbill the purpose of formik is not validation, it's handling forms

Comment: @EllaSharakanski I know. *I'm using Formik for validation in a React app.* said the OP :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inside `Input`, the way you have ordered the props passed to your input element means your `onChange` is being overwritten by Formik's `onChange`. When you create a `Field` with a custom component (i.e. `Input` in your case), Formik passes its `FieldProps` to the component. `FieldProps` contains a property `field` that contains various handlers including `onChange`.

In your `Input` component you do this (I've removed the irrelevant props):

```
<input
    onChange={onChange}
    {...field}
/>
```

See how your own `onChange` will just get replaced by Formik's `onChange()` inside `field`? To make it clearer `...field` is basically causing this to happen:

```
<input
    onChange={onChange}
    onChange={field.onChange}
    // Other props inside "field".
/>
```

If you were to reorder those the console message will now appear:

```
<input
    {...field}
    onChange={onChange}
/>
```

---

However now your input won't work now because you do need to call Formik's `onChange` to let Formik now when your input changes. If you want both a custom `onChange` event and for your input to work properly you can do it like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { color, scale } from "./variables";

const Input = React.forwardRef(
  ({ onChange, onKeyPress, placeholder, type, label, field, form }, ref) => (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
      {label && (
        <label style={{ fontWeight: 700, marginBottom: `${scale.s2}rem` }}>
          {label}
        </label>
      )}
      <input
        {...field}
        ref={ref}
        style={{
          borderRadius: `${scale.s1}rem`,
          border: `1px solid ${color.lightGrey}`,
          padding: `${scale.s3}rem`,
          marginBottom: `${scale.s3}rem`
        }}
        onChange={changeEvent => {
          form.setFieldValue(field.name, changeEvent.target.value);
          onChange(changeEvent.target.value);
        }}
        onKeyPress={onKeyPress}
        placeholder={placeholder ? placeholder : "Type something..."}
        type={type ? type : "text"}
      />
    </div>
  )
);

export default Input;
```

[See it here in action](https://codesandbox.io/s/j7ljpjm6v).

Although overall I'm not really sure what you're trying to do. Your form is working fine, you probably don't need a custom `onChange` but maybe you have some specific use case.

Comment: I am not getting the on change value `changeEvent.target.value`

Comment: I am using react native and  for `changeEvent.target.value` getting `undefined`

Comment: onChange={changeEvent => {props.setFieldValue(props.name, changeEvent.target.value); }}   I searched for hours for this line. Was trying to understand how to use setFieldValue with my custom <input> component. No sign of this in the Formik docs. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks to your comment, i was able to integrate a MarkdownEditor inside formik.
Thank you!

Comment: Current I get same issue, but I'm using typescript. Can you help me to define type for these `{ onChange, onKeyPress, placeholder, type, label, field, form }`

Answer (score 1):

Let me first make it clear this answer is just for help purpose and I do know that this question has been accepted but I do have some modification for above answer with my version if the above solution doesn't work for anyone

**Here onChangeText will return the value of the quantity field**

```
  <Formik
     initialValues={{ product_id: '', quantity: '', amount: '' }}
     onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
        this.submitLogin(values);
     }}

     //some other elements ....
    <Field placeholder='No. of Quantity' name='quantity' component={CustomInputComponent}
        onChangeText={value => {
           console.warn(value); // will get value of quantity
        }}
     />
  />
```

Outside of your class you can define your component

```
const CustomInputComponent = ({
   onChangeText,
   field, // { name, value, onChange, onBlur }
   form: { touched, errors, isValid, handleBlur, handleChange, values, setFieldValue }, // also values, setXXXX, handleXXXX, dirty, isValid, status, etc.
   ...props
}) => {
   return (
      <Input {...field} {...props} onBlur={handleBlur(field.name)}
        onChangeText={value => {
           setFieldValue(field.name, value);
           onChangeText(value); // calling custom onChangeText
        }}
     />
   )
}
```